# How to know SSIS run package issue when trying to execute

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I try to run SSIS with this piece of code:

```
public class EjecutaPaquete {

     private Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package pkgPaquete;
     private Application appAplicacion;

     public DTSExecResult EjecucionPaquete(string str_Paquete, List < CatVariablesEtl > Vars = null) {

       DTSExecResult respuesta;
       try {
         appAplicacion = new Application();

         appAplicacion.PackagePassword = "mypass";

         pkgPaquete = appAplicacion.LoadPackage(str_Paquete, null);

         foreach(CatVariablesEtl item in Vars) {
           pkgPaquete.Variables[item.str_NombreVariable.ToString()].Value = item.str_ValorVariable.ToString();
         }

         respuesta = pkgPaquete.Execute();

         return respuesta;
       } catch (Exception ex) {

         throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

     }
```

It read all variables correctly into foreach, problem is when try to execute package  `respuesta = pkgPaquete.Execute();` first it return `succeeded` but when it return "respuesta" it get `failure`

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to debug the ssis package using visual studio with the same variables values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read errors from `package.Errors` property:

- [msdn - Package.Errors Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.errors.aspx)
- [msdn - DtsErrors.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtserrors.item.aspx)

Code example:

```
foreach(DtsError item in package.Errors) {

     Console.Writeline(item.description);

}
```